# WP_Query / ACF Custom Fields find more than the exact match

Tags: wordpress, sql-like, advanced-custom-fields

I want to make a query for country, male and females.
But i don´t know why, the Query always does not recognize that i requested an exact search.

When i query for `males` it always also querying `(fe)males`.

```
$args_members = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'members',
    'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation'      => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'       => 'country',
        'value'     => $country_site->term_id,
        'compare'   => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'gender',
        'exact'     => true,
        'value'     => '"˙.$gender_query.˙"',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE'
    ),
    )
);

$the_query_members = new WP_Query( $args_members );
```

I also tried a couple of variations manually:

- `'value'     => $gender_query,`
- `'value'     => '"male"',`
- `'value'     => 'male',`

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you query with compare 'LIKE'... and `male LIKE female` is true actually. Change `'compare' => 'LIKE'` to `'compare' => '='`

Comment: OH NOOO really, that simple?!? I spend an hour with it. Thanks!